# Absolute and relative accuracy of a DAC

Tags: dac

I'm working on an assignment to design an R2R DAC. The DAC works, however, I am asked to find the absolute and relative accuracies. I checked on various sources, the definitions seem a bit vague to me.

[image]

Is it one value for each code, or one value for the entire DAC?

[Analog-to-Digital Converison by Analog Devices]

Comment: Why don't you look up a typical R-2R DAC's data sheet and see how they specify things like zero, gain, INR and DNR errors. Those encompass the whole range of possibilities.

Comment: @Andyaka ah good point. I'll check that out now. Thanks!

Comment: The value for the worst (least accurate) code can be used as the value for the DAC.

Answer (score 1):

"Absolute" and "relative" are terms that, by themselves, can be applied on many situations where two values are compared.

"Absolute" means the exact distance of the two compared values (i.e. 4 volts vs 5 volts are 1 volt apart. 1 volt would be the absolute error).

"Relative" means that the same error is divided by the magnitude of the values; for example, if the reference value is 4 volts but we obtain 5 volts, the absolute error is 1 volt, and the relative error is 1 volt divided 4 volts, i.e. 0.25 (or 25%). 25% is an awful precision. If the reference value is 200 volts but we obtain 201 volts, the absolute error is 1 volt (same as before), but the relative error is 1/200 = 0.5% (which is much better than before).

Now, absolute and relative (errors) are both meaningful, and which one to consider depends on the situation.

In case of a DAC, probably "absolute" refers to the "maximum absolute error" that is to be expected along the full interval of outputs, and "relative" refers to the "maximum relative error" we can expect. Often for measurement instruments we are interested in the relative error, so we can measure and know that our measure is correct "not worse than 2%", for example. I think that this makes sense for a DAC too. In both cases, though, may be that the DAC or instruments, in a particular zone (center of scale for example) has more accuracy (or less, who knows).

An example: consider a DAC which has an output of 0-255 volts, with a maximum relative error of 1%. This means that when outputting ideally 250 volts, the real output could be 252.5 volts. Is this absolute error, 2.5 volts, acceptable?

Conversely, imagine a DAC where the maximum absolute error is 2 volts. If I know that I will use output ranges from 1 to 40 volts, the possible error is big. But if I know that I will use an output range from 100 to 200 volts, than that absolute error is not too bad, because it is a relative error of 2% or less.

Answer (score 0):

You measure what each output value of the DAC is and record it, (also the supply voltage to help remove that from causing the deviations)

Absolute error is how large a deviation was there between what the value it output should be and what was measured, e.g. code 256 should have been 5V, you measure 4.96V, you run through your list of values, find the largest one and that is your absolute error

Relative error is how much does that deviation change between codes, e.g. code 256 - 255 should be X voltage apart, what was the largest deviation between 2 codes, that is your relative error.